# show an alert three days later from the beginning date

Tags: php

I need to make a function which will add to the beginning date 3 days and if it's 3 then it shows alert.

```
$beginDate = 2016-07-29 17:14:43 (this one is from sql table format)
$dateNow = date now

if $beginDate + 3 days (72h) is >= $dateNow then echo "It's been three days from..."
```

It seems to be simple but I have hard time to make it work with strtotime() and date() functions. How to code this in PHP?

Comment: check here
https://github.com/rakeshkaswan/missing-date-between-different--ranges

Comment: your question is unclear.

Comment: Can you show what you actually tried?

Comment: actually its hard to explain because the code shows what I need `$beginDate` is a value from data base and I want to check if three days passed from the beginDate, if yes then show message.

Answer (score 1):

```
$beginDate = 2016-07-29 17:14:43 (this one is from sql table format)
$dateNow = date("Y-m-d H:i:s")

if (date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($beginDate.' +3 day')) >= $dateNow){
    echo "3 days to be passed from begin date."
 }else{
    echo "3 days passed from begin date."
 }
```

Comment: it seems to be what I need but I'm not sure how this works because  `echo "It passed three days from the beginning day"` I have to put in an else bracket ??

Comment: @soonic ok, i am modifying my answer

Comment: @soonic check answer, if it seems not work for you, that means i am not able to understand you.

Comment: 1day should be 24h FROM 2016-07-29 17:14:43 TO 2016-07-30 17:14:43. For example If I set 2016-07-30 9:14:43 your code will work also as it would one day which is not good in my case because it's not been 24h.

Comment: this is what I needed `if (strtotime($beginDate)+259200 >= strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"))) { ` both answers helped me to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
 $beginDate = "2016-07-29 17:14:43";
 $beginDate = strtotime($beginDate);
 echo "beginDate ".date('Y-m-d h:i:s', $beginDate);

  $beginDate3Day = strtotime("+3 day", $beginDate);
 $beginDate3Days = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', $beginDate3Day);

 echo "<br />$beginDate3Days "; 
$today = date("Y-m-d h:i:s");

if (beginDate3Days > $today )
echo "It's been three days from..."
```